# Project Euler Problem 1

Tags: python, project-euler

This is my python solution to the first problem on Project Euler:

```
n = 1
rn = 0
while n < 1000:
    if n%3 == 0 or n%5 == 0:
        rn += n
    n = n + 1
print(rn)
```

I would like to find a way to keep everything in this python code to as little number of lines as possible (maybe even a one liner??), and possibly improve the speed (it's currently around 12 ms). By the way, this is the problem:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.Suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: `sum(n for n in range(1000) if not n%3 or not n%5)`

Comment: I like your solution to the problem. It is much more efficiently coded than another Project Euler #1 code question I just read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Python hint number 1:**

The pythonic way to do :

```
n = 1
while n < 1000:
    # something using n
    n = n + 1
```

is :

```
for n in range(1,1000):
    # something using n
```

**Python hint number 2:**

You could make your code a one-liner by using list comprehension/generators :

```
print sum(n for n in range(1,1000) if (n%3==0 or n%5==0))
```

Your code works fine but if instead of 1000, it was a much bigger number, the computation would take much longer. A bit of math would make this more more efficient.

**Math hint number 1 :**

The sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 is really the sum of (the sum of all the multiples of 3 below 1000) plus (the sum of all the multiples of 5 below 1000) minus the numbers you've counted twice.

**Math hint number 2 :**

The number you've counted twice are the multiple of 15.

**Math hint number 3 :**

The sum of the multiple of 3 (or 5 or 15) below 1000 is the [sum of an arithmetic progression.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum)

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, I inputted `100` instead of `1000` @Josay

Comment: Math hint #4: every number that is divideable by an odd number is an odd number itself (so you can skip half of the loop iterations). @Lewis